# How to fill the dropdown list dynamically in symfony? (select the cities of the region)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, symfony, symfony-forms

I explain my problem:

I have to create a form where the drop-down lists are filled according to our choices in the previous ones.

I have two entities:

A Region may have several Cities (ManyToOne) relationship.

I followed the documentation from here [How to Dynamically Modify Forms Using Form Events (Dynamic Generation for Submitted Forms)](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#form-events-submitted-data) .

Here is the code for the entities:

Region entity:

```
class Region
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="nom", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $nom;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="numero", type="smallint")
     */
    private $numero;
}
```

Ville Entity:

```
class Ville
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="nom", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $nom;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="numero", type="smallint")
     */
    private $numero;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="codePostal", type="smallint")
     */
    private $codePostal;

    /**
     * @var Region
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="GE\CandidatBundle\Entity\Region")
     */
    protected $region;
}
```

my problem:

I retrieve the list of regions with the query_builder option but **how do I retrieve the list of cities according to the choice of region**.

AnnonceType:

```
 $builder
->add('region', EntityType::class, [
                'label' => 'Region *',
                'label_attr' => [
                    "class" => "smaller lighter blue",
                    "style" => "font-size: 21px;",
                ],
                'class'         => 'GECandidatBundle:Region',
                'choice_label'  => 'nom',
                'multiple'      => false,
                'query_builder' => function(RegionRepository $repository) {
                    return $repository->getListeRegion();
                }
            ])
            ->add('ville', TextType::class, [
                'label' => 'Ville *',
                'label_attr' => [
                    "class" => "smaller lighter blue",
                    "style" => "font-size: 21px;",
                ],
            ]);
$formModifier = function (FormInterface $form, Region $region = null) {
            $ville = null === $region ? array() : $region->getNom();

            $form->add('ville', EntityType::class, array(
                'class' => 'GECandidatBundle:Ville',
                'placeholder' => '',
                'choices' => $ville,

                'label' => 'Ville *',
                'label_attr' => [
                    "class" => "smaller lighter blue",
                    "style" => "font-size: 21px;",
                ],
                'choice_label'  => 'nom',
                'multiple'      => false,
                /*'query_builder' => function(VilleRepository $repository) {
                    return $repository->getVilleByRegion();
                }*/
            ));
        };

        $builder->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
            function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
                $data = $event->getData();
                $formModifier($event->getForm(), $data->getVille());
            }
        );

        $builder->get('region')->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
            function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
                $region = $event->getForm()->getData();
                $formModifier($event->getForm()->getParent(), $region);
            }
        );
```

new.html.twig:

```
    {{ form_start(form) }}
        {{ form_row(form.region) }}    {# <select id="ge_candidatbundle_annonce_region" ... #}
        {{ form_row(form.ville) }} {# <select id="ge_candidatbundle_annonce_ville" ... #}
        {# ... #}
    {{ form_end(form) }}
<script>
        var $region = $('#ge_candidatbundle_annonce_region');
        $region.change(function() {
            var $form = $(this).closest('form');
            var data = {};
            data[$region.attr('nom')] = $region.val();
            $.ajax({
                url : $form.attr('action'),
                type: $form.attr('method'),
                data : data,
                success: function(html) {
                    $('#ge_candidatbundle_annonce_ville').replaceWith(
                        $(html).find('#ge_candidatbundle_annonce_ville')
                    );
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**

1. I modified the entities.
2. I modified the AnnonceType.
3. I modified the new.html.twig.

Here is the code for the entities:

Region entity:

```
class Region
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="nom", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $nom;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="numero", type="smallint")
     */
    private $numero;
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="GE\CandidatBundle\Entity\Ville", mappedBy="region")
 **/
protected $villes;

/**
 * Get villes
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getVilles()
{
    return $this->villes;
}
}
```

Ville Entity:

```
class Ville
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="nom", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $nom;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="numero", type="smallint")
     */
    private $numero;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="codePostal", type="smallint")
     */
    private $codePostal;

/**
 * @var Region
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="GE\CandidatBundle\Entity\Region", inversedBy="villes")
 */
protected $region;
}
```

AnnonceType:

```
     $builder
    ->add('region', EntityType::class, [
                    'label' => 'Region *',
                    'label_attr' => [
                        "class" => "smaller lighter blue",
                        "style" => "font-size: 21px;",
                    ],
                    'class'         => 'GECandidatBundle:Region',
                    'choice_label'  => 'nom',
                    'multiple'      => false,
                    'query_builder' => function(RegionRepository $repository) {
                        return $repository->getListeRegion();
                    }
                ])
                ->add('ville');
$formModifier = function (FormInterface $form, Region $region = null) {
            $villes = null === $region ? array() : $region->getVilles();

            $form->add('ville', EntityType::class, array(
                'class' => 'GECandidatBundle:Ville',
                'placeholder' => '',
                'choices' => $villes,

                'label' => 'Ville *',
                'label_attr' => [
                    "class" => "smaller lighter blue",
                    "style" => "font-size: 21px;",
                ],
                'choice_label'  => 'nom',
                'multiple'      => false,

            ));
        };

        $builder->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
            function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
                $data = $event->getData();
                $formModifier($event->getForm(), $data->getVille());
            }
        );

        $builder->get('region')->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
            function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
                $region = $event->getForm()->getData();
                $formModifier($event->getForm()->getParent(), $region);
            }
        );
```

new.html.twig:

```
    {{ form_start(form) }}
            {{ form_row(form.region) }}    {# <select id="ge_candidatbundle_annonce_region" ... #}
            {{ form_row(form.ville) }} {# <select id="ge_candidatbundle_annonce_ville" ... #}
            {# ... #}
        {{ form_end(form) }}
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
            var $region = $('#ge_candidatbundle_annonce_region');
            $region.change(function() {
                var $form = $(this).closest('form');
                var data = {};
                data[$region.attr('name')] = $region.val();
                $.ajax({
                    url : $form.attr('action'),
                    type: $form.attr('method'),
                    data : data,
                    success: function(html) {
                        $('#ge_candidatbundle_annonce_ville').replaceWith(
                            $(html).find('#ge_candidatbundle_annonce_ville')
                        );
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Many solutions :

The simplier should be to add `villes` to your `Region` entity and do something like that :

```
class Region
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="nom", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $nom;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="numero", type="smallint")
     */
    private $numero;

    /** @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Ville", inversedBy="region") **/
    protected $villes;

    public function getVilles()
    {
       return $this->villes;
    }

    public function setVilles($villes)
    {
        $this->villes = $villes;

        return $this;
    }
    // [... + get/setVilles functions ...]
}
```

And in your Type :

```
$formModifier = function (FormInterface $form, Region $region = null) {
            $villes = null === $region ? array() : $region->getVilles();

            $form->add('ville', EntityType::class, array(
                'class' => 'GECandidatBundle:Ville',
                'placeholder' => '',
                'choices' => $villes,

                'label' => 'Ville *',
                'label_attr' => [
                    "class" => "smaller lighter blue",
                    "style" => "font-size: 21px;",
                ],
                'choice_label'  => 'nom',
                'multiple'      => false,
                /*'query_builder' => function(VilleRepository $repository) {
                    return $repository->getVilleByRegion();
                }*/
            ));
        };

        $builder->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
            function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
                $data = $event->getData();
                $formModifier($event->getForm(), $data->getVille());
            }
        );

        $builder->get('region')->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
            function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
                $region = $event->getForm()->getData();
                $formModifier($event->getForm()->getParent(), $region);
            }
        );
```

Second option :

uncomment your query builder and implement in your `VilleRepository` your `getVilleByRegion` by passing in argument the `region` entity

**UPDATE**

You set your ajax data with a non existing attribute `nom` replace your javascript code by :

```
<script>
        var $region = $('#ge_candidatbundle_annonce_region');
        $region.change(function() {
            var $form = $(this).closest('form');
            var data = {};
            data[$region.attr('name')] = $region.val();
            $.ajax({
                url : $form.attr('action'),
                type: $form.attr('method'),
                data : data,
                success: function(html) {
                    $('#ge_candidatbundle_annonce_ville').replaceWith(
                        $(html).find('#ge_candidatbundle_annonce_ville')
                    );
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion or debugging sessions; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155618/discussion-on-answer-by-julien-bourdic-how-to-fill-the-dropdown-list-dynamically). If the answer needs to be clarified, it should be [edit]ed, rather than discussed in the comments. If you are having a new problem, you should ask a new question.