# How to dynamically Modify Forms (nested Forms) with symfony?

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine

I followed my example from here [How to fill the dropdown list dynamically in symfony? (select the cities of the region)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46467605/how-to-fill-the-dropdown-list-dynamically-in-symfony-select-the-cities-of-the/46473073#46473073)

I'm trying to make a nested Form, embed a collection of forms inside a form. i have problem with the buildForm.

In my case, I am trying to select the cities of the region for the Company (Entreprise) entity of the Employer (Employeur) entity.

I have a problem with the addition of entity and I also have a problem in the case of enterprise edition.

**When adding the Employer (Employeur) entity: (I can not display the add form)**

This example works well with some entities (a simple form, not nested).

But when I tried it with the Employer entity I got this error:

> Call to a member function getVille() on null

The Stack Trace:

> FatalThrowableError
>   Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Call to a
>   member function getVille() on null
>
> at src\GE\CandidatBundle\Form\EntrepriseType.php:159   at
>   GE\CandidatBundle\Form\EntrepriseType->GE\CandidatBundle\Form{closure}(object(FormEvent),
>   'form.pre_set_data', object(EventDispatcher))   at
>   call_user_func(object(Closure), object(FormEvent),
>   'form.pre_set_data', object(EventDispatcher))
>        (vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher.php:212)
>   at
>   Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->doDispatch(array(object(Closure)),
>   'form.pre_set_data', object(FormEvent))
>        (vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher.php:44)
>   at
>   Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->dispatch('form.pre_set_data',
>   object(FormEvent))
>        (vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\ImmutableEventDispatcher.php:43)
>   at
>   Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\ImmutableEventDispatcher->dispatch('form.pre_set_data',
>   object(FormEvent))
>        (vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Form\Form.php:341)   at Symfony\Component\Form\Form->setData(null)
>        (vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\DataMapper\PropertyPathMapper.php:57)
>   at
>   Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\DataMapper\PropertyPathMapper->mapDataToForms(object(Employeur),
>   object(RecursiveIteratorIterator))
>        (vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Form\Form.php:385)   at Symfony\Component\Form\Form->setData(object(Employeur))
>        (vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Form\Form.php:489)   at Symfony\Component\Form\Form->initialize()
>        (vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder.php:226)
>   at Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder->getForm()
>        (vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Form\FormFactory.php:30)
>   at
>   Symfony\Component\Form\FormFactory->create('GE\CandidatBundle\Form\EmployeurType',
>   object(Employeur), array())
>        (vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\ControllerTrait.php:331)
>   at
>   Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller->createForm('GE\CandidatBundle\Form\EmployeurType',
>   object(Employeur))
>        (src\GE\CandidatBundle\Controller\EmployeurController.php:44)   at
>   GE\CandidatBundle\Controller\EmployeurController->newAction(object(Request))
>   at call_user_func_array(array(object(EmployeurController),
>   'newAction'), array(object(Request)))

Employeur entity:

```
class Employeur extends Utilisateur
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="GE\CandidatBundle\Entity\Entreprise", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    protected $entreprise;
}
```

EntrepriseType:

```
    $builder
            ->add('raisonSocial')
            ->add('region', EntityType::class, [
                'label' => 'Region *',
                'label_attr' => [
                    "class" => "smaller lighter blue",
                    "style" => "font-size: 21px;",
                ],
                'placeholder' => 'Sélectionnez une region',
                'class' => 'GECandidatBundle:Region',
                'choice_label' => 'nom',
                'multiple' => false,
                'query_builder' => function (RegionRepository $repository) {
                    return $repository->getListeRegion();
                }
            ])
            ->add('ville');
$formModifier = function (FormInterface $form, Region $region = null) {
            $villes = null === $region ? array() : $region->getVilles();
            $form->add('ville', EntityType::class, array(
                'label' => 'Ville *',
                'label_attr' => [
                    "class" => "smaller lighter blue",
                    "style" => "font-size: 21px;",
                ],
                'placeholder' => 'Sélectionnez une ville',
                'class' => 'GECandidatBundle:Ville',
                'choice_label' => 'nom',
                'choices' => $villes,
                'multiple' => false,
                'expanded' => false,
            ));
        };

        $builder->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
            function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
                $data = $event->getData();
                $formModifier($event->getForm(), $data->getVille());
            }
        );

        $builder->get('region')->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
            function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
                $region = $event->getForm()->getData();
                $formModifier($event->getForm()->getParent(), $region);
            }
        );
```

My problem is on this line:

> $formModifier($event->getForm(), $data->getVille());

why my example worked well before and now no longer works?

**When modifying the Company (Entreprise) entity: (I can not display the edit form)**

> Type error: Argument 2 passed to
>   GE\CandidatBundle\Form\EntrepriseType::GE\CandidatBundle\Form{closure}()
>   must be an instance of GE\CandidatBundle\Entity\Region or null,
>   instance of Proxies__CG__\GE\CandidatBundle\Entity\Ville given,
>   called in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\GestionEmploi\src\GE\CandidatBundle\Form\EntrepriseType.php
>   on line 159

I have a problem with this line:

> $formModifier = function (FormInterface $form, Region $region = null)

Maybe my problem is in the EmployeurType:

```
$builder
->add('nom')
->add('prenom')
...
->add('entreprise', EntrepriseType::class);
```

Comment: I have the same problem.. yesterday all works right and today the error is showing... I dont understand why... how did you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

On PRE_DATA-SET Event

```
$event->getData() // can be null
```

so code to check if $data != null before you call $data->getVille()

```
$data = $event->getData(); 
$ville = null; 
if ($data != null) 
    $ville = $event->getData()->getVille();
$formModifier($event->getForm(), $ville);
```